# С# Microsoft life cam исключение An exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException'

Tags: c#

У меня появилась проблема мне нужно отобразить изображение с камеры используя api **lifecam** в качестве примера я выбрал этот код

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a491751a-649a-4afc-86a2-32f22c53822d/programming-with-microsoft-hd-lifecam?forum=csharpgeneral

Загрузил библиотеки

> Microsoft.LifeCam.Camera.dll Microsoft.LifeCam.Framework.dll
>   Microsoft.LifeCam.Streamer.dll

```
<Window x:Class="LifeCamWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="379" Width="736"
        xmlns:camera="clr-namespace:Microsoft.LifeCam;assembly=Microsoft.LifeCam.Camera"
        xmlns:foo="clr-namespace:Microsoft.LifeCam;assembly=Microsoft.LifeCam.Streamer">
    <Grid>
        <foo:PreviewView Name="preview" Margin="13,12,10,33"/>
        <Button Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,8" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <ComboBox Margin="0,0,13,8" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="278"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then for your code, do something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace LifeCamWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        bool running = false;
        Microsoft.LifeCam.Streamer streamer;
        const string stop = "Stop";
        const string start = "Start";
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            running = false;
            button.Content = start;
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (running)
            {
                running = false;
                button.Content = start;
                streamer.Stop();
                streamer.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                running = true;
                button.Content = stop;
                var cameras = new Microsoft.LifeCam.CameraList();
                preview.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                streamer = new Microsoft.LifeCam.Streamer(cameras[0], preview, false);
                streamer.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

но к сожалению получаю ошибку компилятора

> An exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException'
>   occurred in PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'Set connectionId threw an exception.' Line
>   number '6' and line position '9'.

В коде xaml на

> xmlns:foo="clr-namespace:Microsoft.LifeCam;assembly=Microsoft.LifeCam.Streamer"

Кроме того на git есть проект https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/WebcamApp/CS этой камеры

Но я немогу его даже запустить он требует Win 10 sdk и UWP, скачать который пока нет возможности

Мои системки VS2015 enterprise, win7 32 bit

Как исправить эту проблему очень надо запустить эту камеру?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась установкой UWP